# sending form information by POST method , cause a 404 error while working on local server

Tags: php, forms, post, methods, get

I'm new in PHP and I'm learning.
I have a problem , I searched the questions like mine , but I didn't find my answer.

an addition the others who asked question like mine were working on a server , but I'm learling and I work on a local server.

these made me create a new question , so please help me

at first let me describe what I am using:(it may help)

I'm using:

---

PhpStorm 2016.3

Build #PS-163.7743.50, built on November 22, 2016

JRE: 1.8.0_51-b16 amd64

JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

---

I created a new php project.

I set PHP language level to 5.6
and I addressed the CLI Interpreter to the php.exe file , in php folder , in XAMPP folder which I have already downloaded.

so my php executable address is:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

as following image , I did not set Debugger extension

[PHP Executable adress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJRZS.jpg)

Now I Describemy problem:

during learning I saw a simple example  about sending a form information by 2 available methods: POST and GET

here is the my form (in myHTML.html file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>POST and GET method Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="myphp.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name" autofocus placeholder="I am..." value=""     REQUIRED>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

as you see , the method is set to : get.
here I have no problem, I fill in the blank with a name , and click on button, the second page appears and says:
you are : ( the name which is entered).

he re is the myPHP.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>POST and GET method Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>you are: <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I set the form method to POST , and change the bellow line:

```
<p>you are: <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?></p>
```

to

```
<p>you are: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?></p>
```

by clicking on the button , the browser generates a 404 page:

in the below pic , I put 2 outputs of GET and POST:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OKhJ.jpg)

I dont know whats going wrong?!

in additional testing I figured that its not important what code is in myphp.php file!

I changed content of myphp.php file to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--    <p>you are: --><?php //echo $_POST["name"]; ?><!--</p>-->

Nothing!!!
</body>
</html>
```

just setting the form method  to POST cause a 404 ERROR!

please help.

Comment: Just for fun change it to $_REQUEST["name"]

Comment: in additional testing I figured that its not important what code is in myphp.php file! just setting the form method to POST cause a 404 ERROR!

Comment: probably a problem with your php installation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with  PhpStorm 2016.3 in Ubuntu 16.10
It turns out that the problem is within PhpStorm build in server. Everything works fine if I run my site (project) in my apache server manually. Try to use a different server.